# Using dialogflow library in App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine-python, dialogflow-es

I am trying to integrate Dialoogflow V2 into my Python/Django WebApp in GAE Flexible Environment. I have followed all the steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/dialogflow/v2beta1), [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring).

The integration works fine locally. Once deployed on the Cloud (no errors on deployment), the application doesnt seem to find the `dialogflow` library, and throws the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError at / No module named 'dialogflow'

Is there anything missing ? How can I get the dialogflow library into GAE Flex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.

The problem was that the appengine_config.py file was not understood by the GAE.
The documentation here (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring) is insufficient.

I included this (https://gist.github.com/jonparrott/4bdd7af14a676f33b099) in my appengine_config.py, excluding the imports of os.path and sys, and that did the trick !